# Bootstrap Datepicker Disable dates not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to put a range of `.datepicker()` selection and [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on&datesDisabled=on#sandbox)

1. I would like to disable some days, however not working,
2. Lets say, Today is Wednesday (04/05/2016) and I would like to restrict the days before first Friday (06/05/2016). For this, I get day of week info from users. Such as; *user selected Saturday*. So the calendar should start with the first Saturday even today is Wednesday, user will not be able to select previous days.

Here is my `.datepicker()` view:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="date-from" class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="date-to" class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the js code:

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#date-from').datepicker({
  //format: 'dd/mm/yy',
  datesDisabled: ['05/06/2016', '05/21/2016'], // not working
  startDate: '+0d',
  weekStart: 1,

  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
  },
  autoclose: true

}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  if (ev.date) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.datepicker("getDate").valueOf() || !checkout.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()) {
      var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
      checkout.datepicker("update", newDate);
    }
  } else {
    checkout.datepicker("update", "");
  }
  $('#date-to')[0].focus();
});


var checkout = $('#date-to').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yy',
  weekStart: 1,
  //endDate: '+2d',
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    if (!checkin.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()) {
      return date.valueOf() >= new Date().valueOf();
    } else {
      return date.valueOf() > checkin.datepicker("getDate").valueOf();
    }
  },
  autoclose: true

}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {});
```

Comment: This can be done using jQuery UI Datepicker. Did you get an answer?